# == in JavaScript returns variable results for same condition

Tags: javascript, equality

On changing the sequence of temp variable in the if condition returns variable results.

```
var temp=1;

var res=(temp++==temp)?"Equal":"Not Equal";
alert(res); //Not Equal

var res=(temp==temp++)?"Equal":"Not Equal";
alert(res); //Equal
```

JS Fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/e9qLK/

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Can someone explain the above behavior?

Comment: Explanation: 1. we get value of `temp`; 2. we compare the value of `temp` to the value of `temp`; 3. we increment `temp`.
`(temp == temp++) - true;`
`(++temp == temp) - false;`
`(temp++ == temp) - false;`
`(temp == ++temp) - false;`

Comment: Read it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: @dsfq the more pertinent reference would be one showing whether the order of evaluation of the LHS and RHS of `==` is defined or not.

Comment: http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.1 suggests that it _is_ defined that the LHS is evaluated before the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple.

In the first, `temp` is incremented, but because it's a *post* increment operator the left-hand side (LHS) of the expression still evaluates to its original value.  Then the right-hand side (RHS) is evaluated, but `temp` was already incremented, so it has the new value.  Then the LHS and RHS are compared - they're no longer equal.

In the second example, the increment happens after the RHS is evaluated, so the LHS and RHS remain equal.

I wouldn't rely on this behaviour.  In other languages ISTR it is explicitly *undefined* behaviour to refer to the same variable more than once in an expression when an increment operator is being used.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `++` after the variable returns the value, *then* increments it.

So in the first example, `temp++` on the left side is 1 but `temp` on the right side is 2.

In the second example, `temp` and `temp++` are both 1.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the order of operations.  Here is what happens in the comparison:

- Evaluate left side expression.
- Evaluate right side expression.
- See if the two are equal.

The postincrement operator (`++`) returns a value and then increments the variable by 1. So in your first case, the first temp has a value of 1, but it increments to 2 before the right side is evaluated.  In the second case, the increment happens after the value of both sides is already obtained.

Note that this behavior is not true in all languages--implementations vary.